# Why does value of the variable changes for all objects

Tags: java

I have a class and age field in that. But when I change age of an object it gets changed for all other objects too for the class.

```
private static int age;
```

Can anybody help resolving this problem?

Comment: What does `static` mean in this context?

Comment: It is static. That means it doesn't belong to an object but to the whole class. Remove the static keyword

Comment: static is class level field, I think you are looking for non static field.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: There is only one instance of your `age` so there isn't any multiple copies for it to be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**static variables** are **class variables** so, remove `static` from variable declaration as :

```
private int age;
```

as per java docs :

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
private int age;
```

static variables are shared between all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Static member belong to whole class, So if you change it all instance get affected.

Use

```
private int age; // without static.
```